# Convolution of probability densities. Having trouble integrating over vector

Tags: probability-theory, integration

First, define a probability distribution with density:

\begin{align*}
\newcommand\bm\boldsymbol
\newcommand{\mbl}{\mathbf{l}}
f(\mbl \mid \bm \alpha)
= \frac{1}{B(\bm \alpha + \bm 1)}\exp\left(\mbl \cdot \bm\alpha\right)
\end{align*}
where
$\mathbf l \in (-\infty,0]^k, \sum_i\exp(l_i) = 1$

I'm having trouble finishing this integral (to calculate the convolution):

\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\mba}{\mathbf{a}}
\newcommand{\mbb}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\mbl}{\mathbf{l}}
\newcommand{\mbp}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\mbv}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\mbx}{\mathbf{x}}
f(\mbl \mid \mba, \mbb)
&= \int_{l_1}^0 \dotsi \int_{l_k}^0 f(\mbx \mid \mba)f(\mbl-\mbx \mid \mbb)d\mbx \newline
&\propto \int_{l_1}^0 \dotsi \int_{l_k}^0 \exp(\mbx \cdot \mba + (\mbl-\mbx) \cdot \mbb)d\mbx \newline
&= \int_{l_1}^0 \dotsi \int_{l_k}^0 \exp(\mbx \cdot (\mba - \mbb) + \mbl \cdot \mbb)d\mbx \newline
&= \prod_{i=1}^k\frac{\exp(a_il_i) - \exp(b_il_i)}{a_i-b_i} ???
\end{align*}

Edit:

After looking at mpiktas's answer, the final line should have been
\begin{align*}
&= \prod_{i=1}^k\frac{\exp(b_il_i) - \exp(a_il_i)}{a_i-b_i}
\end{align*}
which ensures that the terms are all positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\mba}{\mathbf{a}}
\newcommand{\mbb}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\mbl}{\mathbf{l}}
\newcommand{\mbp}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\mbv}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\mbx}{\mathbf{x}}
\int_{l_1}^0 \dotsi \int_{l_k}^0 \exp(\mbx \cdot (\mba - \mbb) + \mbl \cdot \mbb)d\mbx 
&=\exp(\mbl\cdot\mbb)\prod_{i=1}^k\int_{l_i}^0\exp(x_i(a_i-b_i))dx_i\\
&=\exp(\mbl\cdot\mbb)\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{1-\exp(l_i(a_i-b_i))}{a_i-b_i}
\end{align}

That should fix the error in your calculations.

However a lot of questions still remain. What is $B(\alpha+1)$? And if your are trying to compute convolution, why isn't your integration domain $(-\infty,0]^k$?

Comment: thanks!  B is the multinomial beta function, which I think normalizes the distribution correctly.  the domain of integration is such that the arguments passed to f are always negative (l - x <= l - l = 0).